# disable all rows except first row and enable each row when the above row is filled with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html table with 4 rows , i want to only enable the first row and disable all the other 3 rows and **enable second row** when user enter all the details in the **first row** (enter Order ID,select Product1, enter description and select Product2 from dropdown list).
Similarly **enable third row** when user enter all the details in the **second row**..
I tried to use `disabled="disabled"` in the `<tr>` to disable last 3 rows but it is not working as expected.

Another validation check is when user enter the value in the Description column for each row, then only it should check the values user has selected in 
columns Product1 and Product2, show the error message(Product1 and Product2 values cannot be same) if value selected in Product1 and Product2 dropdown list are same.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/7s3QQXrrmaH3nUXQ0td5?p=preview

html code:

```
<table id="productTable" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Product1</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Product2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
        <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
        <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr disabled="disabled">
        <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <select class="product1" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="product2" >
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> <br>
<button name="submit" id="dataButton" onClick="getData()" disabled>Get Data</button>
```

js code:

```
 function populateSelect() {
     var ids = [{"pid":"laptop","des":"laptop"},{"pid":"Mobile","des":"Mobile"},{"pid":"IPAD mini.","des":"IPAD mini."}]
      var productDropdown1 = $(".product1"); 
      var productDropdown2 = $(".product2");
      $.each(ids, function(index,value) {
      $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown1);
        $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown2);
      });

       $("select").change(function() 
       {   
       var row = $(this).closest("tr");
       var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
       var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
       if(product1_drop == product2_drop ){       
            alert('Product1 and Product2 cannot have same value');
      }
   });
 }
```

With the above js code, it is checking the validation when user has selected the value from the dropdown list, but i want when user enter the text in the text box then check if two dropdown list(Product1 and Product2) has the same value and show the error message near that row instead of the pop up dialog box.

Comment: You have to disable the form control elements not the row

Comment: @charlietfl - Can you provide some inputs, thanks in advance

Comment: Well to start can do something like `$('#productTable tbody tr:gt(0) :input').prop('disabled',true)` which should disable all but first row

Comment: thanks for the inputs..still i have problem enabling each row dynamically when only all the fields are filled in the first row, as i need to enable only the immediate row when all the fields are entered in the current row. Surprisingly i could not able to find the appropriate example for the same..thanks.

Comment: depends on use case. Could use a button and validate prior row when it is clicked, or use input event and check if each element on that rows has a value then enable next row

Comment: @charlietfl - Sorry to say but your one line sentences very difficult to understand and many people cannot understand atleast me. Everyone can say orally but atleast providing some links or sample code would reach more users i believe...hope you dont take it in a bad way.thanks

Comment: I don't take it badly. Are you willing to use a button to enable next row? That would be the easiest. What you are doing is a bit complex

Comment: No i don't want to use a button, when the columns Product1, Description and Product2 has a values then i need to enable the immediate next row. Order ID is optional and even if it is blank no need to check.

Comment: What is the point of disabling rows? What happens if the user fills out the first row, fills out the next row, then empties out the values of the first row?

Comment: @NateWhittaker - Point of disabling is as per client requirement they should only have 4 rows and user should allowed filling from first row. And if first row values are emptied out, there will be another check when user click on Get Data button, and error message is shown near row saying need to fill out the required columns.

Comment: @user3684675, what if the user fills out two rows and decides they only want to submit what's in the second row? What if it's easier for the user to fill in data a column at a time (e.g. select all the products, then fill in all the order IDs)? If you're validating the data upon submission anyway, why dictate how the user fills in the form? I don't know your target audience, but some of these client requirements don't seem to be in the best interest of general usability.

Comment: @NateWhittaker - I do understand , but client requirement is different :). He want after first row fields are filled then enable the second row and after second row is filled enable third row...And as you said if user empties out any value in the row while submitting the data need to show the error message..And if user want to submit only second row then need to find out in next client meeting :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then youre trying to do something like my code below. You can use event delegation to have 1 event listener attached to the parent `tr` listening for changes to all your `<input>` and `select` elements within that row.

Have the event listener check if all the `input` elements have a value, if so, remove the `disabled` property from the next elements in the following row using `NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`

```js
function initTable(rowQuantity, columnQuantity) {
  const tbody = document.getElementById('productTable').querySelector('tbody');
  for (let i = 0; i < rowQuantity; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < columnQuantity; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement("td");
      let content = null;
      let option = null;

      switch (j) {
        case 0:
          content = document.createElement("input");
          content.setAttribute("type", "text");
          content.setAttribute("name", "orderNum");
          break;
        case 1:
          content = document.createElement("select");

          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.setAttribute("value", "dog");
          option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Dog"));
          content.appendChild(option);

          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.setAttribute("value", "cat");
          option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cat"));
          content.appendChild(option);

          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.setAttribute("value", "hamster");
          option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hamster"));
          content.appendChild(option);
          break;
        case 2:
          content = document.createElement("input");
          content.setAttribute("type", "text");
          content.setAttribute("name", "description");
          break;
        case 3:
          content = document.createElement("select");

          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.setAttribute("value", "x");
          option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
          content.appendChild(option);

          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.setAttribute("value", "y");
          option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Y"));
          content.appendChild(option);

          option = document.createElement("option");
          option.setAttribute("value", "z");
          option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Z"));
          content.appendChild(option);
          break;
      }

      if (i > 0) {
        content.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
      cell.appendChild(content);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    //Event delegation to the parent
    row.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      const cells = e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('td');
      const selections = Array.prototype.reduce.call(cells, (sum, cell) => {
        if (cell.children[0].value) {
          sum += 1;
        }
        return sum;
      }, 0);

      if (selections === columnQuantity) {
        if (row.nextElementSibling) {
          let nextRowEls = row.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('input');
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(nextRowEls, el => el.disabled = false);
          nextRowEls = row.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('select');
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(nextRowEls, el => el.disabled = false);
        }
      }
    })

    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }
}

initTable(4, 4);
```

```html
<table id="productTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order ID</th>
      <th>Product1</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Product2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but i'm looking much simple way to validate using jquery if possible. thanks.